# Inline queries in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, union

Could someone please show me how to use an inline query in MySQL 5.6
I am trying to do a simple thing! I am trying to write a query in which I select from a table in database and join with an inline table that I am trying to create on the fly.
It's a 1 column table and I am having trouble creating it with multiple rows.

Example inline query

```
select * from (
      (select 'filename1' as file_name) as t1
      union
      (select 'filename2' as file_name) as t2
);
```

If I run this query without the second select statement, then it works.
But if I run it with both select statements and try to union them it breaks down and complains that I have an error in SQL syntax near "as t2".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously a really over-simplified example, but... The members of a `union` query do not take aliases. The derived table that your are creating with `union` does take one, though. So:

```
select * from (
      select 'filename1' as file_name
      union all
      select 'filename2'
) t;
```

Note that:

- there is no need to surround the `union` members with parentheses (unless you want individual `order by` clauses)
- there is no need to alias the column(s) in the second member: the aliases defined in the first query prevail anyway
- unless you *do* want to remove duplicates, use `union all` instead of `union`: it is more efficient, and makes the intent explicit

Finally: as your query stands, there is no need for the outer query. This is equivalent:

```
select 'filename1' as file_name
union all 
select 'filename2'
```

Bonus: in very recent versions of MySQL, you can use the `values row()` constructor:

```
select *
from (values row('filename1'), row('filename2')) t(filename)
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you very much man. It works! I was trying it without aliases for inner select statements but kept the statements in parenthesis, and kept getting errors saying that every subquery must have it's own aliases.

Comment: I don't think mariadb has parity with the row() construct and naming columns with the table alias, but you can at least use values for the second row onward, like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2449915fb0f0942e4d6007a42d14b7f8